# The problem with Include method using on Db context - Asp.Net Core

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, backend, web-deployment

I'v got a backend on Asp.Net Core. Structure of the database looks that:

- User - the basics information about user: login, password etc.
- Profile - this entity is connected to the"User" one to one relation
- Profile photos- each of the users has a own collection of photos.
  This entity is connected to the "Profile"

Here is the "User" entity:

```
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }

        public Profile Profile { get; set; }
    }
```

Then Profile:

```
    public class Profile
    {


        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string BannerImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string ProfileImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }


        public User User { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ProfilePhotos> ProfilePhotos { get; set; }
    }
```

And "ProfilePhotos":

```
    public class ProfilePhotos
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public int ProfileId { get; set; }
        public Profile Profile { get; set; }

    }
```

I want to get all profile photos so I created a endpoint to to that:

```
        [HttpGet("{username}/photos")]
        public IActionResult GetPhotos(string username)
        {
            var profilePhotos = _profileService.GetAllPhotos(username);
            var model = _mapper.Map<IList<ProfilePhotosModel>>(profilePhotos);

            return Ok(model);
        }
```

To get all photos I use a method from "profileService":

```
        public IEnumerable<ProfilePhotos> GetAllPhotos(string username)
        {
            return _context.ProfilePhotos.Include(a=>a.Profile).ThenInclude(b=>b.User).Where(x => x.Profile.User.Username == username);

        }
```

On response I want to get a id of photo, photoUrl and username so I mapped my profile photos to "ProfilePhotosModel"

```
    public class ProfilePhotosModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

    }
```

but unfortunately on response I only get Id and photoUrl. The username is null :(
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: public ICollection<ProfileImages> ProfileImages { get; set; } , is ProfileImages class the same as ProfilePhotos, if not, then can you share ProfileImages code?

Comment: eh sry. I wanted to change to a better matching name, but I missed it. Should be "ProfilePhotos"

Comment: Please provide your mapping code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add custom mapping for the `Username` property.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<ProfilePhotos, ProfilePhotosModel>()
        .ForMember(m => m.Username, exp => exp.MapFrom(p => p.Profile.User.Username));
});
```